# Is there a way to update the phone number (removing spaces) "on the run" after a SOQL entry?

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app

in a customized visualforce page (which I use later in a Lightning app) I take a list of contacts related to a particular account and I make them clickable, linking them to the iOS "Phone" app. Problem is that when a space is present (almost always) things don't work. Is there a way to remove the spaces only from the numbers I display in my app, keeping the original phone number associated to the contact as it was?
Code will probably clarify:
In the constructor:

```
public List<Contact> getContacts()
{
   if(contacts == null)
   {
       contacts = [SELECT Name, Phone, Email FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :account.Id];
   }
   return contacts;
}
```

While in the VF page:`

```
<apex:repeat value="{!contacts}" var="cont_acc">
    <td><apex:outputLink value="tel:{!cont_acc.Phone}">{!cont_acc.Phone}</apex:outputLink></td>
```

Instead of a number like +49 30 12 34 56 78 I would like to have +493012345678 IN MY VF page only, while the content of the contact in Salesforce should not be modified. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use the `SUBSTITUTE` formula in your Visualforce page to do this.

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!'tel:' + SUBSTITUTE(cont_acc.Phone, ' ', '')}">{!cont_acc.Phone}</apex:outputLink>
```

Comment: Hello Alex! It works, thanks a lot. In alternative, <td><apex:outputLink value="tel:{!SUBSTITUTE(cont_acc.Phone,' ', '')}">{!cont_acc.Phone}</apex:outputLink></td> provides exactly the same result, FYI. Cheers, Francesco

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to either a use a wrapper class that receives the contact and has a clean phone variable that is set to the cleaned phone number, or would need to store the cleaned version in a custom phone field on contact that gets sets by in a trigger...

Comment: I will follow the second method (additional field) and let you know if it works (it should, but I'm not a visualforce Jedi yet). Thanks so far! Francesco